# reference a global var in yml file in dbt

Tags: dbt

## Referencing a global variable in a .yml file in dbt

For example, if I have a column or a table name that is defined as a global in my `dbt_project.yml` file:

```yaml
# dbt_project.yml

name: 'my_project'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

vars:
  my_var: 'my_special_var'
```

how can I reference `my_var` in a .yml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways, if you use dbt core, you can export the environment variables e.g.

```
export DBT_USER_NAME=andy
```

then you can reference it in the yaml file:

```
models:
  test_project:
    AA:
      databaseusername: {{ var("DBT_USER_NAME") }}
```

you can also define variables in the yaml file

```
vars:
  test_project:
    env: "dev"
    etl_schema: "etl"

...

models:
  test_project:
    AA:
      database: test_{{ var("env") }}_raw
      schema: {{ var("etl_schema") }}
```

then overwrite the variable value in the command line

```
dbt run --vars '{"env": "prod"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

here's an example from a [github issue comment](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/3450#issuecomment-861649354):

```yaml
# models/sources.yml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: my_source
    tables: "{{ var('my_list_of_tables') }}"
```